# Implementing custom debugger function using breakpoint()

Tags: python, debugging, remote-debugging, vscode-debugger

I am tying to implement a custom debugger function which will only insert a breakpoint if a certain condition is met in a package I am creating:

```
def custom_debug():
    if(condition):
       return breakpoint()
    esle:
       pass
```

However when importing my package in another file:

```
from my_package import module as m

def test():
    print("First")
    m.custom_debug()
    print("Second")
```

This skips through the function and prints both lines. How can I get it do insert a breakpoint using my custom function?

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to pass your condition into custom_debug.
Try this:

```
def custom_debug(condition):
    if condition:
       return breakpoint()
```